# Adding to the objective the absolute differences of numbers that are multiples of decision variables in mixed integer programming

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying for formulate a mixed integer program that optimizes the cost of transferring water through three piping systems.

I have three tanks $S_i$, $i= 1,2,3$. Each tank $S_i$ has $5$ pipes ($j=1$ to $5$) draining the contents to next tank $S_{i+1}$. Each pipe has different flow rates $F_{ij}$. There is a demand $K$ at the end tank $S_k$. $D_{ij}$ is my binary decision variable that decides whether to open a valve $S_i$ or not.

$1$- open the valve, $0$- do not open the valve.

There is a fixed cost $C_{ij}$ to open each pipe. So my total cost of opening pipes is ‘sigma $C_{ij} D_{ij}$’. Now when I optmize this with cost as objective, I get cumulative flowrate of every $S_i$ ‘sigma $D_j$ $F_j$’ for every $i$. These cumulative flow rates are highly different from each other which is highly undesirable in this case. So to minimize that I put a cost to the difference in cumulative flowrates of each system. But when I do so, I end up getting negative values. Say, cum $F_{1j}= 40$ litres/ hr, $F_{2j}=30$, $F_{3j}=50$. Now when I take the differences $1-2$ gives $40-30=10$ and $2$ and $3$ gives $30-50= -20$.

I want to avoid this negative values because it will reduce the objective when the difference exists. I do not want to use absolute value function because that will make my problem non- linear. Can someone help me get absolute values of the difference in cum. Flow rates without making my objective non-linear? Or is there any other way to minimize the differences in cumulative flowrates across three systems?

Comment: I haven't read in enough detail to be sure, but maybe you just need to model the epigraph $t\geq |x-y|$. That is linear, because it is equivalent to $t\geq x-y$ and $t\geq y-x$.

Comment: Anyways, if you are already using binary variables, you can even model $t=|x-y|$ with an extra binary variable.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming x and y are cum. flow rates of different levels, what should the value of t be? Would you please explain me briefly how using extra binary variable will work?

Comment: $t$ is just a variable that bounds $|x-y|$. Minimizing $t$ is equivalent to minimizing $|x-y|$. For the other part see for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#exact-absolute-value

Comment: That works! Thanks! Though this could be one way to handle the problem, I would like to add the cost of the difference between cum. flow rates to the objective function. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Kuifje You are right that $|x-y|\geq t$ requires binary variables, but I was talking about $t\geq |x-y|$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I would like to add the cost of the difference to the objective function (cost of unused capacity to the difference in cum. flow rates across systems). Since quantifying 't', the maximum cap for the difference is not possible in this case.

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence of your last comment.

Comment: The variable 't' is a bound for absolute value of (x-y). In my case, fixing a limit for the difference between cum. flow rates is not possible. So, I want to add the difference between cum. flowrates to the objective function than defining it as a constraint.

Comment: If t is a variable then no limit is imposed. You can add t to the objective (assuming you have a minimization problem).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Min. f= Cij.Dij + absolute(x-y). Cu is my current objective. How do I add t in the objective? Value of t should be absolute(x-y). But i cannot use abs() or min() functions as it will make the problem non linear

Comment: minimize($Cu + t$) subject to ($t\geq |x-y|$)